# How to display "you're logged in as" and keep it showing? (PHP) UPDATE

Tags: php, session

I am letting a "user" log in and I display "you're logged in as username"
That works fine but then after the user clicks a button to add something to SQL the text disappears.

I tried to echo it in another place but then there was only "You're logged as" - there was no user name.

I guess it disappears when I use another "Post" method but why isn't it in `$_SESSION['login']`?

I tried to use `echo $_SESSION['login']`  and there is nothing inside.

How can I make "You're logged as" stay until user logs off?

This is my Logging in part

I find it strange that in `if(isset($_SESSION['zalogowany'])` it has no `$_SESSION['login']` anymore (I tried to echo it there)

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require_once("baza.php");
    //-------Wylogowywanie
    if(isset($_POST['wyloguj']))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['zalogowany']);
        session_destroy();
    }
    //---------Logowanie
    if(!isset($_SESSION['zalogowany'])) 
    {
        if(isset($_POST['wyslij'])) 
        {
            if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT login
            FROM uzytkownicy WHERE login = '".$_POST['login']."'")) > 0) 
            {
                if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT login, haslo, Nr FROM uzytkownicy
                WHERE login = '".$_POST['login']."' 
                && haslo = '".$_POST['haslo']."' ")) > 0 ) 
                {
                    $_SESSION['zalogowany'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
                    $_SESSION['haslo'] = $_POST['haslo'];
                    echo '<font color="red"><center>Jestes zalogowany jako '. $_SESSION['login'].'</center></font>';
                    
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    echo "Zle haslo, prosze sprobowac ponownie";
                    echo "<form method='POST' action='SG.php'>
                        <br><br><input type='submit' value='Logowanie' name='wyloguj'>
                        </form>"; 
            
                }
            } 
            else 
            { 
                echo "Nie ma takiego uzytkownika";
                echo "<form method='POST' action='SG.php'>
                    <br><br><input type='submit' value='Logowanie' name='wyloguj'>
                    </form>"; 
    
    
            }
        } 
        else 
        { 
            echo "<form method='POST' action='SG.php'>
                <b>Nazwa uzytkownika:</b> <input type='text' name='login'><br>
                <br><b>Haslo:</b><br> <input type='password' name='haslo'><br>
                <br><input type='submit' value='Wyslij' name='wyslij'>
                </form>";    


        }
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['zalogowany']))
    {
        
        echo "<form method='POST' action='SG.php'><br><input type='submit' value='Wyloguj' name='wyloguj'></form>"; 
    }
```

Comment: Did you store the username in $_SESSION['login']? Did you remember to start your session?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your session isn't remaining. Add `session_start()` right after the `<?php` tag.

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant since OP updated their code to show they are already including an opening  `<?php` line with `session_start()`. PS, it's bad advice to suggest including meta commentary in posts such as "Edit" or "Update". Just update the post with the content; if users want to see what was done in a given revision, they can click the provided revision history link at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can add this in  your code.

```
 <?php
     if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}
  ?>
```

The session_status() will return

PHP_SESSION_DISABLED if sessions are disabled.
 PHP_SESSION_NONE if sessions are enabled, but none exists.
 PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE if sessions are enabled, and one exists.